# Evaluating integral $\int\limits_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{iwx}}{(x+a)^2+b^2}\,dx$ with contour integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I am trying to evaluate $\displaystyle\int\limits_0^{\infty}\displaystyle\frac{e^{iwx}}{(x+a)^2+b^2}\,dx$ where $w$, $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers. I tried to use the contour integration but since the integral limits are from $0$ to $\infty$ I am not sure which contour I need to use. Does anybody have any idea how to evaluate this integral? Thanks.

Comment: Wait, w is complex or real? (as you just edited)

Comment: Sorry. It is my mistake. $w$ is positive real number.

Comment: shoulnd¡t be the limits $ -\infty $ and $ \infty $  ??

Comment: Do  you have some reason to think that this _can_ be evaluated by complex analysis?

Comment: No, unfortunately, it is from $0$ to $\infty$. Otherwise, it would be quite easy to evaluate it.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, no I don't have any specific reason. Since it looks like a contour integral type integral I think it can be evaluated by using complex analysis methods. If there are any other methods, I will be very appreciated.